# mongodb, how insert new field?

Tags: mongodb

I'm doing an exercise in mongodb. i have a document with the following structure.

```
id    city     temperature
1     cadiz         30
2     sevilla       40
3     cadiz         29
4     sevilla       42
5     malaga        36
6     cadiz         30
7     bilbao        25
8     sevilla       41
```

As inserted in each city could max temp one field value?
example:

```
max_temperature :true;
```

order city and order temperature but not follow ..
thanks. and sorry for my english.

Comment: Do you want `max_temperature` to be `true` for the documents with ids 1, 6, 8, 5, and 7?  Or just 8?

Comment: max_temperature insert in id 1, 6, 4, 5, 7 (group for city and get the max temperature)

Comment: There's no way to do that via a query or an upsert in one operation. If that's not what you mean, you'll need to post the code you've tried.

Comment: @Bicu are you having trouble getting the max?  WiredPrairie is right; you can't do this in one operation, but you can easily get a mapping of cities to max temperatures with a simple `aggregate` command.  Do you need help with that?

Comment: I ordered the cities and temperatures, thus I have. cities grouped and sorted by temperature. the problem is how to put max_emperature in first city in each group. Examples:

Comment: cadiz 30
cadiz 30
cadiz 29
sevilla 42
sevilla 41
sevilla 40
malaga 36
bilbao 25

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you do *not* want to have duplicates (i.e. with two documents of `{city: "Cadiz", temperature: 30}`, only one should be marked as the `max_temperature`, you could execute the following:

```
var lastCity = null;
db.cities.find().sort({city: 1, temp: -1}).forEach(
  function(doc) { 
    if (doc.city != lastCity) {
      db.cities.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{"max_temperature":true}});
    } 
    lastCity = doc.city;
  }
)
```

For the data you provided in your question, the collection would now look like:

```
{ "_id" : 7, "city" : "bilbao", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 25 }
{ "_id" : 1, "city" : "cadiz", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 30 }
{ "_id" : 6, "city" : "cadiz", "temp" : 30 }
{ "_id" : 3, "city" : "cadiz", "temp" : 29 }
{ "_id" : 5, "city" : "malaga", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 36 }
{ "_id" : 4, "city" : "sevilla", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 42 }
{ "_id" : 8, "city" : "sevilla", "temp" : 41 }
{ "_id" : 2, "city" : "sevilla", "temp" : 40 }
```

If you wanted duplicates, i.e. for document 6 to also have `max_temperature : true`, then you would alter the update slightly:

```
var lastCity = null;
var lastTemp = null;
db.cities.find().sort({city: 1, temp: -1}).forEach(
  function(doc) { 
    if (doc.city != lastCity) {
      lastTemp = doc.temp; 
      db.cities.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{"max_temperature":true}})
    } else if (doc.temp == lastTemp) { 
      db.cities.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{"max_temperature":true}})
    } 
    lastCity = doc.city;
  }
)
```

Which would instead give you:

```
{ "_id" : 7, "city" : "bilbao", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 25 }
{ "_id" : 1, "city" : "cadiz", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 30 }
{ "_id" : 6, "city" : "cadiz", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 30 }
{ "_id" : 3, "city" : "cadiz", "temp" : 29 }
{ "_id" : 5, "city" : "malaga", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 36 }
{ "_id" : 4, "city" : "sevilla", "max_temperature" : true, "temp" : 42 }
{ "_id" : 8, "city" : "sevilla", "temp" : 41 }
{ "_id" : 2, "city" : "sevilla", "temp" : 40 }
```

Let me know if that clarifies things a bit!